# send key from component to another component in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react. 
I have 3 main categories namely Breakfast, drinks and desserts in a JSON file.
 
I want to pass it's category code as a parameter/props to the main component and based on code passed it should render respective products under that category which is again coming from a JSON file. 

So in total, I have 4 JSON. 1 for a category, 1 for breakfast menu, 1 for drinks and 1 for a dessert menu.

Below is my code:

```
class ProductList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            data2: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://vendor.com:8080/products/BREAKFAST')
            .then((Response) => Response.json())
            .then((findresponse) => {
                this.setState({
                    data2: findresponse
                })
            })
    }

    renderProducts(categoryCode) {
        return (
            this.state.data2.map((p) => {
                return (
                    <Col key={p.id}>
                        <Breakfast /Drinks/Dessert product={p} />
                        </Col>
                );
            })
        );
    }
    listOfCategories() {
        fetch('http://vendordt.com:8081/category')
            .then((Response) => Response.json())
            .then((findresponse) => {
                this.setState({
                    data: findresponse
                })

            })
    }
    renderCategory() {
        this.listofCategory();
        return (
            this.state.data.map((p) => {
                return (
                    <Col key={p.id}>
                        <Category product={p} />
                    </Col>
                );
            })
        );
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                {this.renderCategory()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ProductList;
```

and

```
class Category extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button key={this.props.product.id} style={{ color: 'grey', radius: '5px', width: '90px' }}>
                    {this.props.product.title}
                </Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Category;
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested and without knowing how your JSONs look like

```
class ProductList extends React.Components {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            categories: {}
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://vendordt.com:8081/category')
        .then((Response) => {
            this.setState({
                categories: Response.json()
            });
        })
        .catch(err => console.error);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="container-fluid">
                {this.state.categories.map(cat => {
                    <Catergory category={cat.categoryCode} />
                })};
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ProductList;
```

and

```
class Category extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            products = {}
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://vendor.com:8080/products/' + this.props.category)
        .then((Response) => {
            this.setState({
                products: Response.json()
            });
        })
        .catch(err => console.error);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.state.products.map( product => (
                    <Button key={product.id} style={{ color: 'grey', radius: '5px', width: '90px' }}>
                        {product.title}
                    </Button>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Category;
```

Comment: Thank you MaddEye

Comment: This is my sample json: { code: 1, title: 'Breakfast 1'},
    { code: 2, title: 'Breakfast 2' },
    { code: 3, title: 'Breakfast 3' }

Comment: also the Category json. I assume for my code something like this { Name: "Breakfast" ...} {Name: "Dessert  ... } and so on

Comment: my category json is like this [{"id":7,"categoryCode":"DESSERTS","name":"Daim cake","description":"Swedish chocolate cake with bits of butterscotch", "price": 20}, {"id":8,"categoryCode":"DESSERTS","name":"choc cake","description":"Swedish chocolate cake with bits of butterscotch", "price": 20},{"id":9,"categoryCode":"DESSERTS","name":"vanila","description":"Swedish chocolate cake with bits of butterscotch", "price": 20}]